# How to hide function and parameter from url in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

this is my URL.

```
 http://localhost/savyy/home/home_page/Islamabad
```

i want to show it like

```
http://localhost/savyy/home
```

i m using uri routing code

```
$route['home/(:any)'] = 'home/home_page/$1;
```

but nothings happen...it shows same URL. can anyone please help me ? please tell me how to hide function name and parameter.

Comment: you can try this routing : `$route['home/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'home/home_page/$1/$2;`

Comment: Since application gets distinctive parameters from URL to make certain DB query or another process on those arguments, you can not remove it and expect application to magically recognise what you had on your mind. You have to pass parameter (I.E. "Islamabad") to let application know which city you want to process on page.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it will work that way, the request is the route to controller. the request uri will be the same. you will still have the "home/home_page/islamabad" in your url. unless you redirect with the home_page() to home() and save the islamabad in a session.